# $K$ Theory of Operators II, Higson's notes

Tags: algebraic-topology, operator-theory, operator-algebras, k-theory

What I want to understand is how the map defined in [proof of Proposition 3.17](http://folk.uio.no/rognes/higson/Book.pdf) is an inverse of the defined map.

> **Proposition 3.17:** For any (ungraded) $C^*$-algebra $A$, the map 
>       $$\Phi:K_0(A) \rightarrow [\mathcal{S}, A \otimes  \mathcal{K} ]$$
>   defined above* is an isomoprhism. Where $\mathcal{S}=C_0(\Bbb R)$, $\mathcal{K}$ compact operators on the graded hilbert space $H=H_0\oplus H_1$.

1. > The map (*) is given as mapping an two idempotent matrix $p,q$ into 
   >   $$
   > f \mapsto
   > \begin{pmatrix}
   > p f(0) & 0 \\
   > 0 & q f(0)
   > \end{pmatrix}
   > $$
   >   where we regard $A \otimes \mathcal{K} \cong M_2(A \otimes \mathcal{K})$. More details of this map is [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3137669/understanding-the-map-from-k-0a-to-homotopy-class-of-maps)
2. > The details of inverse map can be found in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138779/special-elements-in-the-c-algebra-a-otimes-mathcalk?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I could not really chase out how this maps are inverse - in particular, the map in 2. defines an element in $K_0(A \otimes \mathcal{K})$, and here we use Morita equivalence to obtain an element, 
$$K_0(A) \cong K_0(A \otimes \mathcal{K})$$

---

I would be grateful if someone can spell out more details. I believe, it would be easier for one to first read the original proof.